# Generic BackgroundWorker - Populate different DataTables/DataGridViews

Tags: .net, vb.net, datatable, backgroundworker

I have a form with 2 buttons that populate 2 different datagridviews.

There is a generic function that takes in a SQL statement and executes it.

Depending on the SQL statement, this can take some time to execute - so instead of locking up the UI I would like to use a BackgroundWorker so I can show a loading screen while the query is running.

Here's the initial code without BGW:

```vb
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Query1Button_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Query1Button.Click

        Dim sql As String = "SELECT col_1 FROM TABLE_1"
        Dim query1DT As DataTable = getData(sql)

        'now do some other stuff with the datatable
        DataGridView1.DataSource = query2DT
    End Sub

    Private Sub Query2Button_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Query2Button.Click

        Dim sql As String = "WHILE 1=1 SELECT col_2 FROM TABLE_2" 'long running query
        Dim query2DT As DataTable = getData(sql)

        'now do some other stuff with the datatable
        DataGridView2.DataSource = query2DT
    End Sub


    Public Shared Function getData(ByVal sql As String) As DataTable

        Dim sqlcon As New SqlClient.SqlConnection
        Dim sqlcomm As New SqlClient.SqlCommand
        Dim sqlda As New SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter
        Dim sqldt As New DataTable

        sqlcon.ConnectionString = "DBConnection"
        sqlcon.Open()
        sqlcomm.Connection = sqlcon
        sqlcomm.CommandText = sql
        sqlda.SelectCommand = sqlcomm
        sqlda.Fill(sqldt)

        Return sqldt

    End Function
End Class
```

I'd like to wrap the getData function within a new BGW thread, but im unsure exactly how to do it given that there are two different datatables/datagrids that I want to populate.

Here's how I would do it if there was only 1 datagrid:
Imports System.ComponentModel

```
Public Class Form3

    Private Sub Query1Button_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Query1Button.Click

        Dim sql As String = "SELECT col_1 FROM TABLE_1"

        getDataInBackground(sql)

    End Sub

    Private Sub Query2Button_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Query2Button.Click
        Dim sql As String = "WHILE 1=1 SELECT col_2 FROM TABLE_2" 'long running query

        Dim query2DT As DataTable = getData(sql)

        'now do some other stuff with the datatable
        DataGridView2.DataSource = query2DT

    End Sub


    Public Sub getDataInBackground(ByVal sql As String)

        'setup worker
        Dim bw As BackgroundWorker = New BackgroundWorker()
        bw.WorkerReportsProgress = True
        bw.WorkerSupportsCancellation = True
        AddHandler bw.DoWork, New DoWorkEventHandler(AddressOf bw_DoWork)
        AddHandler bw.RunWorkerCompleted, New RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(AddressOf bw_RunWorkerCompleted)
        AddHandler bw.ProgressChanged, New ProgressChangedEventHandler(AddressOf bw_ProgressChanged)

        'Run worker
        bw.RunWorkerAsync(sql)

    End Sub

    Private Sub bw_DoWork(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DoWorkEventArgs)

        Dim returnDT As DataTable
        returnDT = getData(e.Argument)
        e.Result = returnDT

    End Sub
    Private Sub bw_RunWorkerCompleted(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs)
        If e.Cancelled = True Then
            StatusLabel.Text = "Cancelled!"
        ElseIf e.Error IsNot Nothing Then
            StatusLabel.Text = "Error: " & e.Error.Message
        Else

            'now do some other stuff with the datatable
            DataGridView1.DataSource = e.Result

            StatusLabel.Text = "Done!"
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub bw_ProgressChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As ProgressChangedEventArgs)

        'show loading status
        StatusLabel.Text = "Running"
    End Sub

    Public Shared Function getData(ByVal sql As String) As DataTable

        Dim sqlcon As New SqlClient.SqlConnection
        Dim sqlcomm As New SqlClient.SqlCommand
        Dim sqlda As New SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter
        Dim sqldt As New DataTable

        sqlcon.ConnectionString = "DBConnection"
        sqlcon.Open()
        sqlcomm.Connection = sqlcon
        sqlcomm.CommandText = sql
        sqlda.SelectCommand = sqlcomm
        sqlda.Fill(sqldt)

        Return sqldt

    End Function

End Class
```

How can I adapt the BGW to be more generic so I dont have to have "now do some other stuff with the datatable" inside the bw_RunWorkerCompleted sub?

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be able to use the `await` pattern. Instead of putting your logic into the worker, because if it's in the completed event it's a bit more like functional programming.

the `await` keyword will encapsulate your background request. I won't go into detail but there are plenty of tutorials out there. It basically lets you call an operation without jamming up the UI thread, and once it's completed, your code continues on the next line.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZyFL3hjHADs is the tutorial I used I think to learn it.